# How can I access the dom tree of child window?

Tags: javascript

I open a new window using the following code:

```
purchaseWin = window.open("Purchase.aspx","purchaseWin2", "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=700,height=400");
```

I want to access the dom tree of the purchaseWin, e.g.

```
purchaseWin.document.getElementById("tdProduct").innerHTML = "2";
```

It doesn't work. I can only do this:

```
purchaseWin.document.write("abc");
```

I also try this and it doesn't work too:

```
 $(purchaseWin.document).ready(function(){

     purchaseWin.$("#tdProduct").html("2");

   });
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With jQuery, you have to access the [contents](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents) of the document of your child window:

```
$(purchaseWin.document).ready(function () {
  $(purchaseWin.document).contents().find('#tdProduct').html('2');
});
```

Without libraries, with plain JavaScript, you can do it this way:

```
purchaseWin.onload = function () {
  purchaseWin.document.getElementById('tdProduct').innerHTML = '2';
};
```

I think that the problem was that you were trying to retrieve the DOM element before the child window actually loaded.

Comment: The plain Javascript version works.
But jQuery version fails. I need to run the jQuery code manually in parent window to work.

Comment: Works in IE (not firefox):
       $(purchaseWin.document).ready(function () {$(purchaseWin.document).contents().find('#tdProduct').html('2');});

Works in FF (not IE):
        purchaseWin.onload = function () {$(purchaseWin.document).contents().find('#tdProduct').html('2');};

Comment: See Gunni's response, using $(purchaseWin).load for the jQuery option works whereas the document ready event didn't.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe the load event of jQuery works for you as this worked for me in a similar Problem, whereas the ready event did not work:

```
$(purchaseWin).load(function(){
    purchaseWin.$("#tdProduct").html("2");
});
```

Comment: New is that i use the .load event while the accepted answer uses the .ready event. For me that made a difference.

Comment: This is the only answer that gave me access to the dom of the child.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot access the document of a child window if you load a page that does not belong to the domain of the parent window. This is due to the cross-domain security built into Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {

  document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {

    var novoForm = window.open("http://jsbin.com/ugucot/1", "wFormx", "width=800,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titilebar=no,resizable=no,");
    novoForm.onload = function() {
      var w = novoForm.innerWidth;
      var h = novoForm.innerHeight;
      novoForm.document.getElementById("monitor").innerHTML = 'Janela: '+w+' x '+h;
    };
  };
})();
```