# jQuery: receive document ready() on child window

Tags: jquery, dom, window, ready

I'm trying to get notified when the child window I'm opening has its document loaded and ready. This doesn't seem to work:

```
win = window.open(href, 'test', 'width=300, height=400');
win.focus();
$(win.document).ready(function() {
           // Ok, the function will reach here but if I try to manipulate the
           // DOM it doesn't work unless I use breakpoints
           $(this).contents().find("...").doStuff(); // nothing happens
    });
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: thanks McLovin! this helped me solve a similar problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried this? —

```
$(win.document).ready(function() {
    $(win.document).contents().find("...").doStuff();
});
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258563/how-can-i-access-the-dom-tree-of-child-window) discusses something very similar. Duplicate?

Comment: Yes I've tried that as well. If my conslusion from my tests is correct, the problem is that the ready() function is triggered while the DOM tree is not really ready yet..

Comment: Have you tried the plain JS as well, that's mentioned in the answer to the other question?

Comment: Yes it works with manual javascript, thank you! Had to do this:
 win.onload = function() {
     form = $(this.document.getElementById(form_id));
     form.submit(function(evt){

Comment: this doesnt work, win.onload = function() {} is required

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and for me the .load event on the window did work, the .ready did not. So you may try:

```
win = window.open(href, 'test', 'width=300, height=400');
$(win).load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find("...").doStuff(); 
});
```

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome and FF, but IE didn't run the load callback. I ended up adding a self-canceling `setInterval` to check if the child window was ready and run the code.

Comment: I investigated why `ready` doesn't work, so I'll share it.
`$(win.document).ready` is completely equivalent to `$(window).ready`.
See [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.3.1/src/core/ready.js#L13-L26).
(Note: even at the posting time of this question, that is 2011, `ready` works similarly to v3.3.1)
We should use `load` instead of `ready` for the purpose, as Gunni suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.opener` in script on site, which you are loading and execute function defined in global (!) at first page.

Main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.notify = function () {
        alert('runned from opened window');
    };
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.open('test.html');
        }, false);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">Open window</button>
</body>
```

Opened page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        window.opener.notify()
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Popup site
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I can't (don't want to) edit the target site which I'm opening!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code in iframe,

```
$(document,parent.document).ready(function(){
alert('Done');
});
```