# Jquery: how to check if a newly opened window  has been fully loaded? / window loads an external page (like www.yahoo.com)

Tags: jquery, load, notifications, window

the following doesn't work , why ?

```
var myWindow=null;
myWindow = window.open(targetUrlVar,"_blank","resizable=yes");
$(myWindow).load(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Though MyWindow is a Window reference, no check is performed to see whether or not it has been fully loaded. i thought `$(window).load(...)` would work here for "window " being replaced by "MyWindow".

the following works:

```
$(myWindow).load(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

for targetUrlVar being an internal resource (like a  page belonging to my domain) it works.. 
but as soon as i wanted to used the `.load()` or `myWindow.onload()`  with  a `targetUrlVar` being an external page (such as www.yahoo.com or www.google.com ), it doesn't work any more...
No alert is displayed..

i need you help... thank you everyone

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842432/jquery-recieve-document-ready-on-child-window

Comment: $(win.document).ready(function() {
    $(win.document).contents().find("...").doStuff();
});  ?  this only performs when the document is ready... it 's not what i need .. i rather need to be notified when the window is fully loaded !! not as soon the DOM is ready .. thanks though..

Comment: I just tested this out and it seemed to work.  See the test script in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the alert when the child window is open regardless of the state of the child window's DOM then this should work. I also provided a way to test this assumption.

Create a test PHP script (or similar scripting language) with the following content:

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
    <?php sleep(5); // Sleep to delay DOM from loading ?>

    Done sleeping...
</body>
</html>
```

Then call this test page as your child window usingthe following javascript:

```
win = window.open('test.php', 'test', 'width=300, height=400, x=800');
win.focus();
$(win.document).ready(function() {
    alert('Window is open');
});
```

You'll notice that the alert() from the parent window fires before you see "Done sleeping..." appear in the child window.

Comment: i please repeat again : i need to have the alert('window is open') AFTER the window is loaded , NOT when the document of the window is READY... i know your script works, because i have already implemented it. But i need to have AFTER the window has been loaded... that#s why i used i my code above the $(window).load() function with "window" stand for the reference of the newly opened window.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //perform tasks, DOM is loaded
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to be notified when the window is fully loaded: a kind of $(reference_to_window).load(....){}!!! not as soon the DOM is ready ..

Comment: THE WHOLE WINDOW OR PART OF THE WINDOW?

Comment: the whole part, i tried a $(myWindow).load(function(){
}); but it did work... any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is somewhat old.

However, arthur stated,

> for targetUrlVar being an internal resource (like a page belonging to my domain) it works.. but as soon as i wanted to used the .load() or myWindow.onload() with a targetUrlVar being an external page (such as www.yahoo.com or www.google.com ), it doesn't work any more... No alert is displayed..

I think that the issue may be due to the targetUrlVar being external; the alert may be blocked to prevent cross-site scripting (aka XSS).