# How can I modify the contents of one web page from another?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Let me explain my problem, I have a page "A" that contains a textarea.
I have a button on my page "A" that calls a script, this script opens a pop up that contains the page "B".

How could I change something on page "A" from page "B"?

For example retrieve textarea and insert something into it? (Without database)

Thank you!

Comment: So far I've tried different technique that I could avoid it ^ ^

Comment: If you post your code that isn't working, that would probably help.

Comment: I can not, I simplified the problem, my code is a mixture between tinymce, an owner cms etc. ... But the problem remains the same.

Comment: Database, sorry i'm french ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build 2 html pages: test.htm and popup.htm - the test.htm will open the popup.htm, now if you enter something in the popup (textarea) and press the button, the text will be sent to test.htm textarea...:

test.htm

```
<h1>Page A<h1>
<form name="frm">
    <textarea name="txt"></textarea>
    <button onclick="popup('popup.htm')">Open Popup</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function popup (url) {
        win = window.open(url, "window1", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
        win.focus();
    }
</script>
```

popup.htm :

```
<h1>Page B</h1>

<form name="frm">
<textarea name="txt"></textarea>
<button onclick="window.opener.frm.txt.value=document.frm.txt.value">Update Site A</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good SO answer that's quite relevant (and uses jQuery). Basically, you want to manipulate the DOM of a child window (a window opened by your current window):

[How can I access the dom tree of child window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258563/how-can-i-access-the-dom-tree-of-child-window)