# Using Signature Pad in a popup window

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Signature Pad by  Thomas J Bradley [found here](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) inside a javascript popup window. It pops up from a button within a form. Here is the related code:

In the form:
    `<button type="button" id="confirm_button">Confirm</button>`

in a document.ready function:

```
$("#confirm_button").on("click", function() { 
    var left  = ($(window).width()/2)-(900/2),
    top   = ($(window).height()/2)-(600/2),
    popup = window.open ("/add-signature.php", "popup", "width=400, height=400, top="+top+", left="+left);
});
```

which opens a window to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Views/templates/default/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/sigpad/jquery.signaturepad.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sigpad/flashcanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sigpad/jquery.signaturepad.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sigpad/json2.min.js"></script>


<title>SMB | Add Signature</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="component">
            <h1>Sign your Name</h1>
        <form method="post" action="" class="sigPad">
          <label for="name">Print your name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">

          <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
          <ul class="sigNav">

            <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it">Draw It</a></li>
            <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="sig sigWrapper">
            <div class="typed"></div>
            <canvas class="pad" height="55"></canvas>
            <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
          </div>
          <button type="submit">I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});
});



    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is this: How do I get the signature from the popup window into an input on the form on the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your popup, use the window.opener object, which is a reference to the global window object of the parent page. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416117/how-can-i-modify-the-contents-of-one-web-page-from-another/11416809#11416809) of sending from the popup to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/rongxike/pen/MJMopq
You can use it with popup signature pad.
If you get what you want, I am happy.

```
 var sign = $('#txt').SignaturePad({
                allowToSign: true,
                img64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
                border: '1px solid #c7c8c9',
                width: '300px',
                height: '150px',
                callback: function (data, action) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            var sign = $('#txt2').SignaturePad({
                allowToSign: true,
                img64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
                border: '1px solid #c7c8c9',
                width: '300px',
                height: '150px',
                callback: function (data, action) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });



    (function () {
         var __slice = [].slice;

         (function ($) {
             var Sketch;
             $.fn.sketch = function () {
                 var args, key, sketch;
                 key = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
                 if (this.length > 1) {
                     $.error('Sketch.js can only be called on one element at a time.');
                 }
                 sketch = this.data('sketch');
                 if (typeof key === 'string' && sketch) {
                     if (sketch[key]) {
                         if (typeof sketch[key] === 'function') {
                             return sketch[key].apply(sketch, args);
                         } else if (args.length === 0) {
                             return sketch[key];
                         } else if (args.length === 1) {
                             return sketch[key] = args[0];
                         }
                     } else {
                         return $.error('Sketch.js did not recognize the given command.');
                     }
                 } else if (sketch) {
                     return sketch;
                 } else {
                     this.data('sketch', new Sketch(this.get(0), key));
                     return this;
                 }
             };
             Sketch = (function () {

                 function Sketch(el, opts) {
                     this.el = el;
                     this.canvas = $(el);
                     this.context = el.getContext('2d');
                     this.options = $.extend({
                         toolLinks: true,
                         defaultTool: 'marker',
                         defaultColor: '#000000',
                         defaultSize: 2
                     }, opts);
                     this.painting = false;
                     this.color = this.options.defaultColor;
                     this.size = this.options.defaultSize;
                     this.tool = this.options.defaultTool;
                     this.actions = [];
                     this.action = [];
                     this.canvas.bind('click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', this.onEvent);
                     if (this.options.toolLinks) {
                         $('body').delegate("a[href=\"#" + (this.canvas.attr('id')) + "\"]", 'click', function (e) {
                             var $canvas, $this, key, sketch, _i, _len, _ref;
                             $this = $(this);
                             $canvas = $($this.attr('href'));
                             sketch = $canvas.data('sketch');
                             _ref = ['color', 'size', 'tool'];
                             for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                                 key = _ref[_i];
                                 if ($this.attr("data-" + key)) {
                                     sketch.set(key, $(this).attr("data-" + key));
                                 }
                             }
                             if ($(this).attr('data-download')) {
                                 sketch.download($(this).attr('data-download'));
                             }
                             return false;
                         });
                     }
                 }

                 Sketch.prototype.download = function (format) {
                     var mime;
                     format || (format = "png");
                     if (format === "jpg") {
                         format = "jpeg";
                     }
                     mime = "image/" + format;
                     return window.open(this.el.toDataURL(mime));
                 };

                 Sketch.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
                     this[key] = value;
                     return this.canvas.trigger("sketch.change" + key, value);
                 };

                 Sketch.prototype.startPainting = function () {
                     this.painting = true;
                     return this.action = {
                         tool: this.tool,
                         color: this.color,
                         size: parseFloat(this.size),
                         events: []
                     };
                 };


                 Sketch.prototype.stopPainting = function () {
                     if (this.action) {
                         this.actions.push(this.action);
                     }
                     this.painting = false;
                     this.action = null;
                     return this.redraw();
                 };

                 Sketch.prototype.onEvent = function (e) {
                     if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
                         e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
                         e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
                     }
                     $.sketch.tools[$(this).data('sketch').tool].onEvent.call($(this).data('sketch'), e);
                     e.preventDefault();
                     return false;
                 };

                 Sketch.prototype.redraw = function () {
                     var sketch;
                     //this.el.width = this.canvas.width();
                     this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
                     sketch = this;
                     $.each(this.actions, function () {
                         if (this.tool) {
                             return $.sketch.tools[this.tool].draw.call(sketch, this);
                         }
                     });
                     if (this.painting && this.action) {
                         return $.sketch.tools[this.action.tool].draw.call(sketch, this.action);
                     }
                 };

                 return Sketch;

             })();
             $.sketch = {
                 tools: {}
             };
             $.sketch.tools.marker = {
                 onEvent: function (e) {
                     switch (e.type) {
                         case 'mousedown':
                         case 'touchstart':
                             if (this.painting) {
                                 this.stopPainting();
                             }
                             this.startPainting();
                             break;
                         case 'mouseup':
                         //return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
                         case 'mouseout':
                         case 'mouseleave':
                         case 'touchend':
                         //this.stopPainting();
                         case 'touchcancel':
                             this.stopPainting();
                     }
                     if (this.painting) {
                         this.action.events.push({
                             x: e.pageX - this.canvas.offset().left,
                             y: e.pageY - this.canvas.offset().top,
                             event: e.type
                         });
                         return this.redraw();
                     }
                 },
                 draw: function (action) {
                     var event, previous, _i, _len, _ref;
                     this.context.lineJoin = "round";
                     this.context.lineCap = "round";
                     this.context.beginPath();
                     this.context.moveTo(action.events[0].x, action.events[0].y);
                     _ref = action.events;
                     for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                         event = _ref[_i];
                         this.context.lineTo(event.x, event.y);
                         previous = event;
                     }
                     this.context.strokeStyle = action.color;
                     this.context.lineWidth = action.size;
                     return this.context.stroke();
                 }
             };
             return $.sketch.tools.eraser = {
                 onEvent: function (e) {
                     return $.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, e);
                 },
                 draw: function (action) {
                     var oldcomposite;
                     oldcomposite = this.context.globalCompositeOperation;
                     this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                     action.color = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
                     $.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, action);
                     return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
                 }
             };
         })(jQuery);

     }).call(this);


     (function ($) {
         $.fn.SignaturePad = function (options) {

             //update the settings
             var settings = $.extend({
                 allowToSign: true,
                 img64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
                 border: '1px solid #c7c8c9',
                 width: '300px',
                 height: '150px',
                 callback: function () {
                     return true;
                 }
             }, options);

             //control should be a textbox
             //loop all the controls
             var id = 0;

             //add a very big pad
             var big_pad = $('#signPadBig');
             var back_drop = $('#signPadBigBackDrop');
             var canvas = undefined;
             if (big_pad.length == 0) {

                 back_drop = $('<div>')
                 back_drop.css('position', 'fixed');
                 back_drop.css('top', '0');
                 back_drop.css('right', '0');
                 back_drop.css('bottom', '0');
                 back_drop.css('left', '0');
                 back_drop.css('z-index', '1040 !important');
                 back_drop.css('background-color', '#000');
                 back_drop.css('display', 'none');
                 back_drop.css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=50)');
                 back_drop.css('opacity', '0.5');
                 $('body').append(back_drop);

                 big_pad = $('<div>');
                 big_pad.css('display', 'none');
                 big_pad.css('position', 'fixed');
                 big_pad.css('margin', '0 auto');
                 big_pad.css('top', '0');
                 big_pad.css('bottom', '0');
                 big_pad.css('right', '0');
                 big_pad.css('left', '0');
                 big_pad.css('z-index', '1000002 !important');
                 big_pad.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                 big_pad.css('outline', '0');
                 big_pad.css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');

                 big_pad.css('right', '0');
                 big_pad.css('border', '1px solid #c8c8c8');
                 big_pad.css('padding', '15px');
                 big_pad.css('background-color', 'white');
                 big_pad.css('margin-top', '15px');
                 big_pad.css('width', '95%');
                 big_pad.css('height', '90%');
                 big_pad.css('border-radius', '10px');
                 big_pad.attr('id', 'signPadBig');
                 $('body').append(big_pad);

                 var update_canvas_size = function () {
                     var w = big_pad.width() //* 0.95;
                     var h = big_pad.height() - 55;

                     canvas.attr('width', w);
                     canvas.attr('height', h);
                 }


                 canvas = $('<canvas>');
                 canvas.css('display', 'block');
                 canvas.css('margin', '0 auto');
                 canvas.css('border', '1px solid #c8c8c8');
                 canvas.css('border-radius', '10px');
                 //canvas.css('width', '90%');
                 //canvas.css('height', '80%');
                 big_pad.append(canvas);

                 update_canvas_size();
                 $(window).on('resize', function () {
                     update_canvas_size();
                 });

                 var clearCanvas = function () {
                     canvas.sketch().action = null;
                     canvas.sketch().actions = [];       // this line empties the actions.
                     var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
                     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas[0].width, canvas[0].height);
                     return true
                 }

                 var _get_base64_value = function () {
                     var text_control = $.data(big_pad[0], 'control');  //settings.control; // $('#' + big_pad.attr('id'));
                     return $(text_control).val();
                 }

                 var copyCanvas = function () {
                     //get data from bigger pad
                     var sigData = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");

                     var _img = new Image;
                     _img.onload = resizeImage;
                     _img.src = sigData;

                     var targetWidth = canvas.width();
                     var targetHeight = canvas.height();

                     function resizeImage() {
                         var imageToDataUri = function (img, width, height) {

                             // create an off-screen canvas
                             var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                                 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                             // set its dimension to target size
                             canvas.width = width;
                             canvas.height = height;

                             // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
                             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                             // encode image to data-uri with base64 version of compressed image
                             return canvas.toDataURL();
                         }

                         var newDataUri = imageToDataUri(this, targetWidth, targetHeight);
                         var control_img = $.data(big_pad[0], 'img');
                         if (control_img)
                             $(control_img).attr("src", newDataUri);

                         var text_control = $.data(big_pad[0], 'control');  //settings.control; // $('#' + big_pad.attr('id'));
                         if (text_control)
                             $(text_control).val(newDataUri);
                     }
                 }

                 var buttons = [
                     {
                         title: 'Close',
                         callback: function () {
                             clearCanvas();
                             big_pad.slideToggle(function () {
                                 back_drop.hide('fade');
                             });

                         }
                     },
                     {
                         title: 'Clear',
                         callback: function () {
                             clearCanvas();
                             if (settings.callback)
                                 settings.callback(_get_base64_value(), 'clear');
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         title: 'Accept',
                         callback: function () {
                             copyCanvas();
                             clearCanvas();
                             big_pad.slideToggle(function () {
                                 back_drop.hide('fade', function () {
                                     if (settings.callback)
                                         settings.callback(_get_base64_value(), 'accept');
                                 });
                             });
                         }
                     }].forEach(function (e) {
                     var btn = $('<button>');
                     btn.attr('type', 'button');
                     btn.css('border', '1px solid #c8c8c8');
                     btn.css('background-color', 'white');
                     btn.css('padding', '10px');
                     btn.css('display', 'block');
                     btn.css('margin-top', '15px');
                     btn.css('margin-right', '5px');
                     btn.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                     btn.css('border-radius', '5px');
                     btn.css('float', 'right');
                     btn.css('height', '40px');
                     btn.text(e.title);
                     btn.on('click', function () {
                         e.callback(e.title);
                     })
                     big_pad.append(btn);

                 });

             }
             else {
                 canvas = big_pad.find('canvas')[0];
             }

             //init the signpad
             if (canvas) {
                 var sign1big = $(canvas).sketch({ defaultColor: "#000", defaultSize: 5 });
             }

             //for each control
             return this.each(function () {

                 var control = $(this);
                 control.hide();

                 //get the control parent
                 var wrapper = control.parent();
                 var img = $('<img>');

                 //style it
                 img.css("cursor", "pointer");
                 img.css("border", settings.border);
                 img.css("height", settings.height);
                 img.css("width", settings.width);
                 img.css('border-radius', '5px')
                 img.attr("src", settings.img64);

                 if (typeof (wrapper) == 'object') {
                     wrapper.append(img);
                 }




                 //init the big sign pad
                 if (settings.allowToSign == true) {
                     //click to the pad bigger
                     img.on('click', function () {
                         //show the pad
                         back_drop.show();
                         big_pad.slideToggle();

                         //save control to use later
                         $.data(big_pad[0], 'img', img);
                         $.data(big_pad[0], 'control', control);

                         //settings.control = control;
                         //settings.img = img;
                     });
                 }
             });
         };


     })(jQuery);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.