# window.open: is it possible open a new window with modify its DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, window

I want open a new window：

```
var my = window.open('iframe.html', '_blank' ,"height=600, width=600");
```

but just when open it, I want modify its DOM, I have tried:

```
var div = my.document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Hello!";
my.document.body.appendChild( div );
```

or:

```
var div = $('<div>Hello World</div>');
$(my).contents().find('body').append(div);
```

Both of them doesn't work;

So is it possible modify my iframe DOM when I open it?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258563/how-can-i-access-the-dom-tree-of-child-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to access and modify the iframe DOM only **before** the child window is loaded.

```
var my = window.open('iframe.html', '_blank' ,"height=600, width=600");

my.onload = function () {
 var div = my.document.createElement("div");
 div.innerHTML = "Hello!";
 my.document.body.appendChild( div );
};
```

Also, make sure that the parent window is not closed before the child window is loaded.