# Open a html in new tab and access it's DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a requirement where if I click a button a function is called which will
1. Open a given html link in new tab
2. And access the newly opened html's DOM

I am trying something like this in my function call:

```
function GenerateReport() {
window.open('./qunit/EditOpenSave.html','_blank');
//////window.location.href = "./qunit/EditOpenSave.html";
document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = "Show me !!!";
}
```

But here it successfully opens the link, while not accessing it's DOM.
Please help..

Comment: Please try searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258563/how-can-i-access-the-dom-tree-of-child-window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this way and it's working !!!

```
function GenerateReport() {
newTab = window.open('./qunit/EditOpenSave.html','_blank');
$(newTab.document).ready(function () {
$(newTab.document).contents().find('#inputTextToSave').html("asdfasdf");
});
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me actually I don't want to edit html just add access element