# Get HTML contents of child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the HTML contents of a child window, and then take those contents and append it to the parent window. It is not working!!!! It alerts 'undefined' every time. Very annoying. How do I get this to work?

JavaScript in the parent Window:

```
function openW() {
  var url = this.href,
      childW =  window.open(url);

  // shows .html class of child window

  alert($(childW.document).find('.hidden').html());

}

$('.item').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    openW();
});
```

Then in the HTML of the parent window, I have a link to the child window and a class of 'item'.

Also, even in the console log, if I type **childW**, it shows 'undefined'. I don't know what is going on.

**EDIT**

Based off the duplicate in question, here is the code I tried:

```
childW = window.open(url);
$(childW.document).ready(function () {
  alert($(childW.document).contents().find('.hidden').html());
});
```

Not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access the dom tree of child window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258563/how-can-i-access-the-dom-tree-of-child-window)

Comment: I have seen that question and tried the code, but it did not work. Let me update my HTML for the possible duplicate.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with a popup window, but you can use the jQuery `contents()` function on an `iframe`.

Comment: If possible , can post `html` ? Is `this` at `var url = this.href`  defined ? Thanks

Comment: Yes,  it is defined.

Comment: Try `$(childW.document).contents().find('.hidden').html()`
without `.ready()` . See http://api.jquery.com/contents/