# How manipulate DOM elements after window.open("_self")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want dynamically load a full screen image by clicking on it (normal size).

So I have

CSS

```
.full-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').on("click", function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var myWindow = window.open("img.html");
        var src = img.attr('src');
        var document1 = myWindow.document;
        $(myWindow.document).ready(function() {
            alert();
            $(myWindow.document).contents().find('#image').attr('src', src);
        });
    });
});
```

I tried this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258563/how-can-i-access-the-dom-tree-of-child-window)`in each variant but the best result I achieve is in the pasted javascript code: new window is opened and only after pressing the alert, image is loaded ONLY in the new window.

I would the image loaded in the same window, but obv adding "_self" doesn't work.

The new html page is like this `<img id = "image" class = "full-image"/>`

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle please.?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The image should already be loaded in your window. What exactly is supposed to happen to the image?

Comment: If you want it in same window than just simple [do it this way](http://jsfiddle.net/z3p9wz32/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you're asking for. Here's one solution.

Wrap the image in a normal `a` tag. Set the `href` to be `/img.html?src=x`, where x is the `img src`.

On img.html, have some Javascript to get the value from the URL (there's a method for doing that on Stack), and then set the `img src` on that page to that value.

JsFiddle isn't ideal, 'cos its a single-page thing, but I've tried to show you how it would work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/s8dws2yy/). The selectors will need slight adjustment.